# how to setup a web app with model view controller on CentOS beside using Tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications

I'm working on a project that the customer specifically want `Java` to be the back-end technology. My team wants to see, if there is a *good way* of implementing it, without having to deal with `Struts` (they all hate `Tomcat` & `Struts` setup for some reason). So, given that I have total control over a `CentOS` server running `Apache`; is there a good way of setting up an environment, where the `HTML` could call `Java` code and `Java` code could control the view on the HTML page?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a Servlet Container in this case. **Tomcat is your best bet**, but you can go for Resin or Jetty, I suppose.

You can avoid Struts, and have a look to some other MVC framework i.e. Wicket, Stripes, Play etc. Spring MVC is another powerful and great framework, in case you want to use Spring as an IoC as well. IMO, it will pay to adapt Spring.

By the way, Struts 2 is not that bloated like Classic Struts, and doesn't require that much of XML configurations. A lot of things can be done using annotation. But I still suggest to check **Spring with Spring MVC/Stripes/Wicket/Struts2**.